# How can I store data using loops

Tags: python, loops

I have an assignment

> (Find the highest score) Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number
> of students and each student’s score, and displays the highest score. Assume that
> the input is stored in a file named score.txt, and the program obtains the input from
> the file.

However we haven't learned how to store data in a .txt file yet so the teacher told us to just treat it as inputs.

What I have so far:

```
grade = 0

students = eval(input("enter number of students: "))

for i in range(1, students + 1):
    grade = eval(input("enter student score: "))
```

I understand how to input number of students and store it in to a variable (students).

And I know how to write a loop to repeatedly ask for the input (student score) equal to the number of students

but I don't know how to store each students score separately other than doing it once under the for loop (grade).

Comment: Sounds like you're overthinking the problem. `grade = input()` within the loop **is storing data**. With that information, what else should you store to track the previous input so you can compare the value just received with a maximum seen so far? If you were to do this by hand, what would you do? Translate that

Comment: I would typically just write a bunch of inputs and assign them to a variable, but I think that's not possible because the number of students will change.  I see how simple it is now with the solution below.

Comment: You can also `append()` to a `list` datatype. Then call `max()` function on it.

Comment: As a side note, it's good to avoid using `eval` (and the similar `exec`) if at all possible; in the vast majority of situations there's a better way to do it without them, while using them often leads to massive security holes. For example, in this case you don't need `eval` at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
students = int(input("enter number of students: "))
highest_grade = 0
for i in range(1, students + 1):
    grade = int(input("enter student score: "))
    if grade > highest_grade:
        highest_grade = grade

print("Highest score is {}".format(highest_grade))
```

I just run and tested. Its working fine

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be useful for you to explain what changed

Comment: @OneCricketeer You are right.  You already know but for the questioner, Its simple that store the maximum score and ignore the rest of the scores < current maximum score

Answer (score 0):

Well you can also try using dictionary. Store student names as well as their scores. Then check for the highest score. You code:

```
students=int(input ("Enter no of students: "))
scores={}
hg=0
for i in range(students):
    name=input("Enter name of student= ")
    score=int(input ("Enter score: "))
    scores[name]=score
    if score>hg:
        hg=score
print("Highest score is ",hg)
```

Explaination: we'll take input for both name as well as score from user and store it in dictionary. By default, we'll save hg(highest score) as 0. Then while taking user input for score, we'll check whether it greater than hg, if yes, update hg to new score and keep checking it until the loop terminates and finally print it

You do this stuff without dictionary and list, I just suggested dictionary because it can save data in more systematic way showing both name as well as score